# Call cascade style sheet using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where I need to call the main css file using javascript into the header section. So basically instead of having the below line within the headers

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

How can I call it using javascript within the header tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this

```
document.head.innerHTML+='<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">';
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but looks good. thanks. what does `+=` mean here?

Comment: @Bekki append operator?

Comment: Works perfect. :) I'll mark it as answered in couple of minutes. +25

Comment: @Bekki +25 will be after 9 mins, when you can accept :D Now you can give only +10.

Comment: just one quick question. If I need to add two css files, could this be written in a single line or do I need to repeat `document.head.innerHTML+=''` twice?

Comment: @Bekki Single line is enough. No need to repeat. `document.head.innerHTML+='<link ...><link...>...'` would be valid.

Comment: So doing this is okay `document.head.innerHTML+='<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main1.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main2.css">';` ?

Comment: @Bekki Yes, absolutely okay.